# Why doesn't search for word under cursor (* and #) turn on search highlighting and how do I enable it?

Tags: search, highlight

I can't find info in help about whether it should or shouldn't turn on highlighting, but I find it strange that I have to press `n` or `N` after `*` or `#` to turn on search highlighting.

How do I enable this in vim if that's 'normal' behaviour.

I've got only these lines in my vimrc related to search highlighting.

```
if !has('nvim')
    set smartcase
    set hlsearch      " highlight search terms
    set incsearch     " show search matches as you type
endif
```

Comment: This is the default behavior for `hlsearch`. Try starting vim with `vim -u NONE`, then put `:set hlsearch` and see if the behavior is unchanged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook up the `hlsearch` command like so:

```
nnoremap * :set hlsearch<CR>*
nnoremap # :set hlsearch<CR>#
```

And if you want to highlight the current word without moving the cursor you can add the `N` movement afterwards:

```
nnoremap * :set hlsearch<CR>*N
nnoremap # :set hlsearch<CR>#N
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. Do you have any idea what the logic behind vim default behaviour?